# Avoid line breaks in Blade template output

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

This may sound trivial but I haven't found a related post.

How do I avoid generation of line breaks in Blade template output? e.g. the following loop spits out one option per line (physical line break after each iteration, not `<br>`):

```
[
@foreach ($Collection as $row)
  "{{ $row->Abbreviation }}"{{ ($loop->last? '' : ',') }}
@endforeach
]
```

I would expect it to generate something like:

```
["Option 1","Option 2", "Option 3"]
```

Instead it generates this:

```
[
"Option 1",
"Option 2",
"Option 3"
]
```

And while this works, I want my output to be more tidy. Is there a way to ask Blade engine not to add line breaks?

I'm using Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in one line only.

```
[@foreach ($Collection as $row) "{{ $row->Abbreviation }}"{{ ($loop->last? '' : ',') }}@endforeach]
```

it will generate an output like this

```
["Option 1","Option 2", "Option 3"]
```

Comment: Yep. Works precisely like that. Thanks a ton.